# How to change a function inside connect in react to mapStateToProps?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using redux in my react project. I'm still getting used to redux. So I have a little knowledge in redux. Here what I need to do is pass mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps.(`export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddTicket);`). But now I'm having it in a different format. Is there a way to put this code inside mapStateToProps?

```
export default connect(
  (state) => {
    const ticketTypeArr = state.ViewTickets.typeEnum;
    const ticketStatusArr = state.ViewTickets.statusEnum;
    const ticketPriorityArr = state.ViewTickets.priorityEnum;

    const { inProgress, error } = state.Tickets.createTicketStatus;
    return {
      inProgress,
      error,
      ticketTypeArr,
      ticketStatusArr,
      ticketPriorityArr
    };
  },
  (dispatch) => bindActionCreators({ createTicket }, dispatch),
  mapDispatchToProps
)(AddTicket);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const ticketTypeArr = state.ViewTickets.typeEnum;
    const ticketStatusArr = state.ViewTickets.statusEnum;
    const ticketPriorityArr = state.ViewTickets.priorityEnum;

    const { inProgress, error } = state.Tickets.createTicketStatus;
    return {
      inProgress,
      error,
      ticketTypeArr,
      ticketStatusArr,
      ticketPriorityArr
    };
 };

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  createTicket: () => dispatch(createTicket())
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(AddTicket);
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeEnum' of undefined
It means state becomes undefined then

Comment: try to do console.log(state) before your const `ticketTypeArr` and see if you have your data from the state

Comment: Yeah I tried that.It gives as undefined.But before adding changing the function it worked

Comment: I've updated the answer, in your question you have 3 parameters added to the connect function, I don't know how it worked before.